# Booting problem

Tags: boot, ssd

I install updates every day and since 1st of Feb. I have booting issues with my Elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) (U 16.04 LTS) but not every time though. I turn on my PC. sda5 screen shows up, I enter the password and all I get is either a blank black screen or pulsing logo of elementary OS. After few tries it loads the login screen to my account. I don't have a clue what is the problem... maybe twice the sda5 screen showed me something with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> I guess? But I am not quite sure, cause it flashes so quickly.
Any suggestions how to solve this without reinstalling the whole PC and possibly losing all of my settings, installs etc.? (Btw, I am using new SSD)

Sorry for my English... I am European :D

Comment: What do you mean by SDA5 screen?